# Enumerate all possible distributions of n balls into k boxes

Tags: algorithm, matlab, combinations, permutation, combinatorics

The exact problem i am referring to and the number of distributions for the  problem is computed [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1441337/184201). I am interested in knowing those distributions explicitly.

For example, there are 5 balls and 3 boxes: one distribution is 2 balls in box 1, 2 in box 2, 1 in box 3 referred to as, say 221. Now i want to list all such possible distributions: -

212

131

104

.
.
.

One way is that i run the matlab command: `perms([0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1])`. This essentially generates all permutations of 5 balls and 2 sticks. but there is massive over-counting as the command `perms` does not recognize identical objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very simple ... sort of.

```
function alloc(balls, boxes):

    if boxes = 1
        return [balls]
    else
       for n in range 0:balls
           return alloc(balls-n, boxes-1)
```

That's the basic recursion logic: pick each possible quantity of balls, then recur on the remaining balls and one box fewer.

The list-gluing methods will be language-dependent; I leave them as an exercise for the student.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`unique()`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/unique.html) to get rid of identical rows generated by `perms()`:

```
A = unique(perms([0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1]), 'rows');
% `A` will contain all combinations, not permutations, of [0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1]
```